# Summer'20 Release - Salesforce Communities - CSP Error in Chrome

Tags: customer-community, csp, content-security-policy, summer20

I have a Customer Community login page which is using a lightning aura component.
Login page has a section where user enters username and password and logs in.

After Summer'20 release, the section to enter credentials is disappeared.
In the browser console, it shows an error as shown in the screenshot:

The issue started appearing in this weekend's Summer'20 release. Prior to that it was working fine.

If we add *.googleapis.com and *.gstatic.com to CSP Trusted Sites, the errors go away but the login section still doesn't show.

**This happens only in Chrome browser. It works in fine IE, Edge, Firefox browsers and even works in Chrome incognito mode.**

[image: Error in Customer Community login page-Chrome browser only]

Google introduced following update to, SameSite Cookie Behavior which can Break Salesforce Integrations. This is being enforced for Chrome v80+ starting 14-Jul.

[Google Chrome - SameSite Cookie Behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351874&type=1&mode=1)

Only action item regarding this change as per the above salesforce article is to ensure that the Require Secure Connections (HTTPS) checkbox is selected, for the community site. I have checked this and it is already selected.

I couldn't find any known issue on Salesforce site regarding this.

Anyone has any idea, why this might be happening?